# Laravel 5 - Eloquent ORM update all

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

How can i update everything in a table usins Eloquent? Is there any prepared function for this?

I do not want solution with using DB if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model::where('id', '>', 0)->update(['field' => $value]);
```

should work. Not sure if just this will work too:

```
Model::update(['field' => $value]);
```

Comment: The second query works just fine. However note that this will not trigger model events or make use of any other special Eloquent feature.